# How do i draw a hemisphere using SphericalPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I want to know what ranges must be set for theta and to get a hemisphere of radius 5 from SphericalPlot3D.

Answer (score 4):

And if you want a hemisphere in an arbitrary orientation you can do this.

```
normal = {1, 3, 2};
SphericalPlot3D[5, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, {x, y, z}.normal >= 0]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Makes it easy to get the cut anywhere you like.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SphericalPlot3D[5, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, π}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the orientation you want. bill s' answer makes a meridianal cut, one common way to cut the sphere in half. Here is another. This one make an equatorial cut.

```
SphericalPlot3D[5, {θ, 0, π/2}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]
```

plot.png[image]